# Html Chat Or Something With Parameters

Tags: html, parameters, chat, history

Well, I almost don't know anything about this language, so I need help!

I need codes/scripts that I can paste to my website, or copy the files on the server... then make that work.
I used to copy random ones but nothing worked.

What exactly I need:
-A chat that appears on the page
-That chat should with with URL parameters, like: www.site.com/message="Hello", so that message appears on the page
-All messages should be saved in a file on server, for example "history.txt", and that history should load by loading the page...

Is that all simple? Possible?
Thanks if anyone get me an answer(s)!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use PHP to do this. If you use the GET method, parameters can be passed through the url, and it's very easy to read and write files. Where are you coding at the moment?

Comment: Thank you for responding! I been waiting... :)
Well, I am using one of file managers in 000webhost.com
There inside is default.php file (the page) so I open it and try to code something (but I am really bad at it)...

Comment: There is also an website: https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2011-03-19-build-real-time-chat-10-lines-code/
That one has an easy chat in 10 lines, so I wonder if there is way to hide the Chat Input (chat box) and to send a message by URL bar with parameters...
If not - then I hope someone would answer here...